# fwrite() alternative for large files on 32-bit system

Tags: c, windows, file-io

I'm trying to generate large files (4-8 GB) with C code.
Now I use `fopen()` with `'wb'` parameters to open file binary and `fwrite()` function in `for` loop to write bytes to file. I'm writing one byte in every loop iteration. There is no problem until the file is larger or equal to 4294967296 bytes (4096 MB). It looks like some memory limit in 32-bit OS, because when it writes to that opened file, it is still in RAM. Am I right? The symptom is that the created file has smaller size than I want. The difference is 4096 MB, e.g. when I want 6000 MB file, it creates 6000 MB - 4096 MB = 1904 MB file.

Could you suggest other way to do that task?

Regards :)

Part of code:

```
unsigned long long int number_of_data = (unsigned int)atoi(argv[1])*1024*1024; //MB
char x[1]={atoi(argv[2])};

fp=fopen(strcat(argv[3],".bin"),"wb");

    for(i=0;i<number_of_data;i++) {
        fwrite(x, sizeof(x[0]), sizeof(x[0]), fp);
    }

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: `strcat(argv[3],".bin")` wrong

Comment: @willys `i` is definied this way: `unsigned long long int i = 0;`

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is an excellent question.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I get the name of file which I want to create from command line. Why is it wrong?

Comment: there is no guarantee that regions that can bind to ". bin" are prepared. It might have destroyed the program.

Comment: which os and which file system do you use?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens I use Windows 7 32bit and NTFS partition.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It seems to be too complex for me. Could you tell me how to do it in other way?

Comment: I think the answer to this question is compiler/OS specific. Please specify compiler/OS.

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I need to find more specific info about compiler, now I don't know where is this.

Comment: What are your symptoms?

Comment: e.g. `char filename[256]; strcat(strcpy(filename, argv[3]), ".bin");`

Comment: Not the problem you're posting about, but `fwrite(x, sizeof(x[0]), sizeof(x[0]), fp);` -- this snippet smells bad. If you intend to write the size of each element instead of the element itself, your data write size is probably wrong. If you intend to write the data and not the size of the data, your write content is definitely wrong. Finally... writing a multiGig file one byte (or one size_t) at a time is a really silly idea.

Comment: What @BLUEPIXY is telling you is you do not have the right to modify what argv[x] points to by appending to it; you damage whatever comes after. That's why he later says to create your own copy and append to that copy.

Comment: D'oh. I just typed out a really long answer explaining how to use O_LARGEFILE, then saw your comment. Oh well.

Comment: @mah thanks for explanation. I want just repeat one byte data to fill all the file (with declared size) with that value. Its purpose is to test some hardware transmission. It's long time since I was using C last time, I don't if that snippet is good or not. I just saw that it writes that value to the file :)

Comment: MY FAULT! Sorry guys. That problem is when declared file size is bigger than or equal to 4096 MB. It starts then again from 0. E.g. when I want 4095 MB it makes 4095 MB; when I want 4096 MB it makes 0 MB file; when I want 4097 MB it makes 1 MB file. So it is overflow on some level, but I don't know where.

Comment: Have you tried calling `fflush()` every now and then?

Comment: Not sure if I understand how to use it, but I tried now with `fflush(fp);` after `fwrite()`. It doesn't help. No change in result.

Comment: I see now that VS shows warning: "integral constant overflow" to something like this: `unsigned long long int test_variable = 4096*1024*1024;`. This is unwanted and surprising behaviour for me.

Comment: @bLAZ I understand now. The reason that line of code smells bad is that you're using sizeof(x[0]) to declare the number of elements you're writing. It will actually work since x is an array of chars, however I would suggest you change it to sizeof(x) instead because as a practice, if the type of elements of x were to change, sizeof(x) would still work while sizeof(x[0]) would no longer (happen to) be the number of elements. sizeof(x[0]) is of course still the size of each element for parameter #2.

Comment: Thank you all for help and explanations:) Solution from second answer helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fwrite` is not the problem here. The problem is the value you are calculating for `number_of_data`.

You need to be careful of any unintentional 32-bit casting when dealing with 64-bit integers. When I define them, I normally do it in a number of discrete steps, being careful at each step:

```
unsigned long long int number_of_data = atoi(argv[1]); // Should be good for up to 2,147,483,647 MB (2TB)
number_of_data *= 1024*1024; // Convert to MB
```

The assignment operator (`*=`) will be acting on the l-value (the `unsigned long long int`), so you can trust it to be acting on a 64-bit value.

This may look unoptimised, but a decent compiler will remove any unnecessary steps.

Comment: This solution helped me :) That was indeed problem with that variable value. But many thanks to all people answering in this question. It was very useful and informative.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have any problem creating large files on Windows but I have noticed that if you use a 32 bit version of seek on the file it then seems to decide it is a 32 bit file and thus cannot be larger that 4GB. I have had success using _open, _lseeki64 and _write when working with >4GB files on Windows. For instance:

```
static void
create_file_simple(const TCHAR *filename, __int64 size)
{
    int omode = _O_WRONLY | _O_CREAT | _O_TRUNC;
    int fd = _topen(filename, omode, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
    _lseeki64(fd, size, SEEK_SET);
    _write(fd, "ABCD", 4);
    _close(fd);
}
```

The above will create a file over 4GB without issue. However, it can be slow as when you call _write() there the file system has to actually allocate the disk blocks for you. You may find it faster to create a sparse file if you have to fill it up randomly. If you will fill the file sequentially from the beginning then the above code will be fine. Note that if you really want to use the buffered IO provided by fwrite you can obtain a FILE* from a C library file descriptor using fdopen().

(In case anyone is wondering, the TCHAR, _topen and underscore prefixes are all MSVC++ quirks).

**UPDATE**

The original question is using sequential output for N bytes of value V. So a simple program that should actually produce the file desired is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <tchar.h>
int
_tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    __int64 n = 0, r = 0, size = 0x100000000LL; /* 4GB */
    char v = 'A';
    int fd = _topen(argv[1], _O_WRONLY | _O_CREAT| _O_TRUNC, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
    while (r != -1 && n < count) {
        r = _write(fd, &v, sizeof(value));
        if (r >= 0) n += r;
    }
    _close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this will be *really* slow as we are only writing one byte at a time. That is something that can be improved by using a larger buffer or using buffered I/O by calling fdopen on the descriptor (fd) and switching to fwrite.

Comment: Your MSVC++ quirks work fine under MinGW(-w64) GCC as well; they are quirks of the Windows C Runtime library, not the compiler.

Comment: Probably that is what I'm looking for, but I'm not far away from "Hello World" and now it is hard for me to use it in a way that I want :D Please give me a moment.

Comment: @patthoyts Could you tell me how to give filename to that function?

Comment: Something like this: `TCHAR fname[] = "Name";` cannot be used... I have no idea how to run this function.

Comment: @patthoyts By larger buffer you mean writing more than one byte in iteration? For me it is not important to write only one byte every time, so then... where is the limit for such a chars table/buffer size?

Comment: TCHAR is a MS defined type that compiles to either char or wchar_t depending on UNICODE being defined. It is endemic in Windows C/C++ code. You would use `TCHAR fname[] = _T("Name");` to create an array of chars appropriate to the current compilation environment. Basically on Windows98 and older, TCHAR was char but on NT, XP and newer TCHAR is wchar_t (unicode capable).

Answer (score 1):

Yuo have no problem with `fwrite()`. The problem seems to be your

```
unsigned long long int number_of_data = (unsigned int)atoi(argv[1])*1024*1024; //MB
```

which indeed should be rather something like

```
uint16_t number_of_data = atoll(argv[1])*1024ULL*1024ULL;
```

`unsigned long long` would still be ok, but `unsigned int * int * int` will give you a `unsinged int` no matter how large your target variable is.

Comment: So this is why I get that overflow warning. But it tells me now that `atoll` is undefined :/ I have `#include < stdlib.h >`.

Comment: try #include <string.h> and use _strtoui64 (or _tcstoui64 if using TCHAR types).

Comment: I will try this solution tomorrow but it will probably help as like @Lee Netherton solution (the same problem issue). Thanks.